# Functions of Package not Available if Registered Through Another Package

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have a base package that I want to use to manage all my package dependencies. In building this package my aim is to install and register all dependent packages.

I have successfully been able to register the service providers of each package (they show up as loaded when dd($app);).

Unfortunately I am not able to access any functionality from any of the sub-packages.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Method <ServiceProviderMethod> does not exist.
```

The following is the service provider of the main package:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BonesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('genealabs/bones');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->register('GeneaLabs\BonesMacros\BonesMacrosServiceProvider');
        $this->app->register('GeneaLabs\BonesFlash\BonesFlashServiceProvider');
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

If I register the two sub-packages independently in app.php config file, they work just as expected, so I don't think anything is wrong there. My guess is that I am not exposing something through the main package, but I have no idea what I'm missing.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

**Update:**
For debugging I created the main package in workbench in a new Laravel app, to keep namespace "contamination" to a minimum. I was able to install it, but now its throwing errors on the $this->register lines that it cannot find the namespaces listed, even though those packages were developed under those namespaces.

I updated the register method in the main package's service provider as follows:

```
public function register()
{
    $bonesMacroServiceProvider = new BonesMacrosServiceProvider($this->app);
    $bonesFlashServiceProvider = new BonesFlashServiceProvider($this->app);
    $this->app->register($bonesMacroServiceProvider);
    $this->app->register($bonesFlashServiceProvider);
}
```

But this had no use either, still receiving the same error, that it can't find the methods in the sub-packages.

**Update 2**

After undoing the last bit there with the instanciation in the register method, I did some more investigating. Now dd()'ing the $app variable shows that none of my packages are actually registered, event the main package I manually included in app.php. So far it appears that:

- The main package fails to register, because it errors out on composer update.
- Composer update complains that it can't see the dependent packages' namespace to register them.
- The dependent packages' namespace isn't available for registering, because composer hasn't installed them yet.

This seems like a vicious catch-22. Is there anyway to avoid this? Could I check for namespace and only attempt to register a package if the namespace exists?

**Update 3**

By modifying the register() method in the main package's service provider, I was able to get composer to run successfully now:

```
public function register()
{
    if (class_exists('GeneaLabs\BonesMacros\BonesMacrosServiceProvider')) {
        $this->app->register('GeneaLabs\BonesMacros\BonesMacrosServiceProvider');
    }
    if (class_exists('GeneaLabs\BonesFlash\BonesFlashServiceProvider')) {
        $this->app->register( 'GeneaLabs\BonesFlash\BonesFlashServiceProvider' );
    }
}
```

However, the original issue still remains that I am unable to access any of the functionality in the sub-packages.

Answer (score 0):

this post is a few months old but I think this is helpful here. I do it this way (laravel 4.2):

in my service provider:

```
// for adding package alias
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;

public function boot() {

    // ...laravel stuff

    // register the service provider for the child package
    $this->app->register('Vendor\Package\PackageServiceProvider');
}


public function register() {

    // loader for config namespaces
    $loader = $this->app['config']->getLoader();

    // get the config environment name
    $env = $this->app['config']->getEnvironment();

    // add the folder to the package config files to the config loader namespace
    $loader->addNamespace('package',__DIR__.'/../../../../../../app/config/packages/vendor/package');

    // perform the "override" (load config data)
    $configs = $loader->load($env,'config','package');

    // override config data in global config array
    $this->app['config']->set('package::config',$configs);

    // add the alias for the child package
    AliasLoader::getInstance()->alias('Former', 'Depends\On\Package');
}
```

This way you can keep the child package untouched because you can override the config file laravelish style.

So everything included like alias, service provider and config file (optionally overwritten)